# How to eliminate zero value data bar in POI XSSFWorkbook

Tags: java, apache-poi

I create a XSSFWorkbook to have data bars shown as the official example. 
http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/ss/examples/ConditionalFormats.java.
My question is why the zero value also shows the bar, how can i eliminate it? [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wm4Cz.png).

```html
static void dataBars2(XSSFSheet sheet) {

  XSSFFont font = sheet.getWorkbook().createFont();
  font.setFontName("等线 Regular");
  font.setFontHeight(12.0);
  CellStyle cs = sheet.getWorkbook().createCellStyle();
  cs.setDataFormat((short) 10);
  cs.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
  cs.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.THIN);
  cs.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.THIN);
  cs.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.THIN);
  cs.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.THIN);
  cs.setLeftBorderColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.index);
  cs.setFont(font);
  CellStyle cs_m = sheet.getWorkbook().createCellStyle();
  cs_m.setDataFormat((short) 3);
  cs_m.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
  cs_m.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.THIN);
  cs_m.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.THIN);
  cs_m.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.THIN);
  cs_m.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.THIN);
  cs_m.setFont(font);

  CellStyle cs_header = sheet.getWorkbook().createCellStyle();

  cs_header.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.THIN);
  cs_header.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.THIN);
  cs_header.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.THIN);
  cs_header.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.THIN);

  XSSFColor color1 = new XSSFColor(new Color(218, 225, 240));
  cs_header.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
  ((XSSFCellStyle) cs_header).setFillForegroundColor(color1);

  cs_header.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);

  Row r = sheet.createRow(0);
  Cell c00 = r.createCell(0);
  c00.setCellValue("Data Bars");
  c00.setCellStyle(cs_header);
  Cell c01 = r.createCell(1);
  c01.setCellStyle(cs_header);
  c01.setCellValue("Green Positive");

  List<Double> list = Arrays.asList(0.279, 0.252, 0.187, 0.128, 0.078, 0.043, 0.022, 0.012, 0.011, 0.0, 0.0);
  for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
   r = sheet.createRow(i + 1);
   Cell c0 = r.createCell(0);
   c0.setCellValue(10000 + i);
   c0.setCellStyle(cs_m);
   Cell c = r.createCell(1);
   c.setCellValue(list.get(i));
   c.setCellStyle(cs);
  }

  sheet.setColumnWidth(0, 3000);
  sheet.setColumnWidth(1, 5000);

  XSSFSheetConditionalFormatting sheetCF = sheet.getSheetConditionalFormatting();

  ExtendedColor colorA = sheet.getWorkbook().getCreationHelper().createExtendedColor();
  colorA.setARGBHex("FF80C279");
  CellRangeAddress[] regions1 = {CellRangeAddress.valueOf("B2:B12")};
  XSSFConditionalFormattingRule rule1 = sheetCF.createConditionalFormattingRule(colorA);
  XSSFDataBarFormatting db1 = rule1.getDataBarFormatting();
  db1.getMinThreshold().setRangeType(RangeType.MIN);
  db1.getMaxThreshold().setRangeType(RangeType.MAX);
  sheetCF.addConditionalFormatting(regions1, rule1);
 }
```

PS: The HSSFWorkbook don't show the zero value data bar with the same data.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious answer would be setting [XSSFDataBarFormatting.setWidthMin](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFDataBarFormatting.html#setWidthMin-int-) to 0. But this cannot work since it is simply not implemented yet. See [XSSFDataBarFormatting.java](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_4_0_1/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFDataBarFormatting.java?view=markup#l57).

So we need doing this using low level underlying class `org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTDataBar`.

Example:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFDataBarFormatting;

import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class ConditionalFormattingDataBars {

 public static void applyDataBars(SheetConditionalFormatting sheetCF, String region, ExtendedColor color) throws Exception {
  CellRangeAddress[] regions = { CellRangeAddress.valueOf(region) };
  ConditionalFormattingRule rule = sheetCF.createConditionalFormattingRule(color);
  DataBarFormatting dbf = rule.getDataBarFormatting();
  dbf.getMinThreshold().setRangeType(ConditionalFormattingThreshold.RangeType.MIN);
  dbf.getMaxThreshold().setRangeType(ConditionalFormattingThreshold.RangeType.MAX);

  dbf.setWidthMin(0); //cannot work for XSSFDataBarFormatting, see https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_4_0_1/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFDataBarFormatting.java?view=markup#l57
  dbf.setWidthMax(100); //cannot work for XSSFDataBarFormatting, see https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_4_0_1/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFDataBarFormatting.java?view=markup#l64

  if (dbf instanceof XSSFDataBarFormatting) {
   Field _databar = XSSFDataBarFormatting.class.getDeclaredField("_databar");
   _databar.setAccessible(true);
   org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTDataBar ctDataBar =
    (org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTDataBar)_databar.get(dbf);
   ctDataBar.setMinLength(0);
   ctDataBar.setMaxLength(100);
  }

  sheetCF.addConditionalFormatting(regions, rule);
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("new sheet");

  java.util.List<Double> list = java.util.Arrays.asList(0.279, 0.252, 0.187, 0.128, 0.078, 0.043, 0.022, 0.012, 0.011, 0.0, 0.0);
  for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
   sheet.createRow(i+1).createCell(1).setCellValue(list.get(i));
  }

  SheetConditionalFormatting sheetCF = sheet.getSheetConditionalFormatting();
  ExtendedColor color = workbook.getCreationHelper().createExtendedColor();
  color.setARGBHex("FF80C279");
  applyDataBars(sheetCF, "B2:B12", color);

  sheet.setColumnWidth(1, 50*256);

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("ConditionalFormattingDataBars.xlsx");
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();

 }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: excellent, it is a nice solution. However,  if setMinLength to zero, the min value will not show data bar even it is not zero. I know it can be solved by judging if the dataset contains zero, is there better way?

Comment: @qingyang: ??? This is exactly what this threshold says: Data bars having length 0% (or whatever is set) of column width for the minimum value in range up to  length 100%  (or whatever is set) of column width for the maximum value in range. So if `MinLength` is set 0, then the minimal value has 0 length data bar, independent of if minimal value is 0 or not. This is exactly what `Excel 2007` is able to do. Do not comparing that with later `Excel` versions which have extended settings there. Those extended settings are not implemented in underlying `ooxml-schemas` beans of `apache poi`.

Comment: Okay, thank you for patient explanation. I do know the threshold mean. It is a product demand to show data bar depend on whether the value is zero. It can be done when operating in excel manually.  As you said, may be the ooxml-schemas beans don't support this settings.

Comment: @qingyang: "It can be done when operating in excel manually." What Excel version? `Apache poi` mainly bases on [Ecma Office Open XML File Formats Standard - Final draft - 9th of October 2006](http://www.ecma-international.org/news/TC45_current_work/TC45-2006-50_final_draft.htm) which is `Excel 2007`.

Comment: Excel 2016 for Mac.