# How to create conditional formatting data bar gradient fill with Apache POI and Java?

Tags: java, conditional-statements, formatting, apache-poi

I have a list of percents in an excel file I create

[image]

In Excel file I can select this percents and select Home -> conditional Formatting -> data bar -> gradient fill
[image]

And now it became like this

[image]

Now I need to do the same but using Apach POI and java, but I don't know how to do it.
Could you please provide me with an example how to do it?
It would be perfect if someone could fill the gap, in this example:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.SheetConditionalFormatting;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class ConditionalFormattingExample {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("new sheet");
    String[] list = new String[]{"5%", "-5%", "10%", "-25%"};
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        sheet.createRow(i).createCell(0).setCellValue(list[i]);
    }
    SheetConditionalFormatting sheetCF = sheet.getSheetConditionalFormatting();
    
    //--???
    
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("ConditionalFormattingExample.xlsx");
    workbook.write(out);
    out.close();
    workbook.close();
}
}
```

Comment: Create the formatting in Excel, read it back in Apache POI, and see how Excel encoded it?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68772734/how-to-add-negative-value-for-databar-in-apache-poi/68773621#68773621